# Axios interceptors do not send the request

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

I am currently doing a project where I need to use axios interceptors. I have watched several guides and read some instructions. Sadly, when I try to implement the interceptors, they do not work. What I am trying to do is at least see if the request has been send. However, the main goal is to check if the current token has expired and assign a new one.

Here is the assignment of axiosInstance with some data:

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://142.93.134.108:1111/me",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"),
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

And here is code from one of the components where I try to send the request right when it mounts:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        return response;
      },
      function (error) {}
    );
  }
```

I understand that I probably do not use interceptors properly, so if possible could you please send some great resources to understand this topic.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/davidtucker/ps-serverless-app/blob/e44782b565da447412bcdce969659fd52c429d45/webapp/src/services/index.js#L12-L30) might be useful to you.  It was for me.

Comment: @kyrlolv did this solve your problem? I'll write up a fuller answer if so and you can accept it (and hopefully upvote it :D)

Comment: @Hcaertnit I'm still figuring it out, but your resource is helpful, so yeah, you can write the answer to my questtion)